# Convergence of improper Integral $\lim_{x -> 0} x^{\mu+n}{{\log x}\over {1+x}}$

Tags: improper-integrals

$$\int_0^1{{x^n\log x}\over {(1+x)^2}} $$
*My Attempt* :

The integrand is unbounded for $x=0$. so,

Using $\mu-Test$ , the integral will be convergent if $0<\mu<1$ such than$$\lim_{x -> 0} x^{\mu+n}{{\log x}\over {1+x}}$$ exists

The limit converges for $\mu+n>0$ or $\mu>-n$ This is true for all $n>0$ Hence the given integral must converge for all $n>0$

The answer however given is that the integral is convergent for $n>-1$, How do i deduce that, ans is there another simpler work around ?

Answer (score 0):

If $n>0$ the integrand *is* bounded at zero, as you can see using [L'Hospital rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

If $-1<\mu<n<0$, then

$$\dfrac{|x^n\ln x|}{1+x^2} < x^\mu$$

for $x$ *sufficiently close to 0*. Since the integral of $x^\mu$ converges, your integral converges too.